# Assing to data.frame bases on a vector value leaving the rest untouched

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

Thanks for your time here.

I have this old code in FORTRAN that I was asked to convert to R. Involves a bunch of lines, all within a while loop and in there I have some calculations I need to perform on the data structures based in a condition vector, leaving the rest of the arrays untouched. The data is not important in this example but in the following code what I need is to perform the y and z assignments just for the elements corresponding to the cond vector if they are TRUE, otherwise, the value of that index remains intact

```
s    <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
v    <- c(12965, 150086, 994637, 304718, 22960, 2524, 20608)
df1  <- data.frame(s=s, n=c(52, 158, 56, 19, 8, 7, 0))
df2  <- data.frame(s=s, n=c(23, 542, 433, 65, 5756, 12, 1))
cond <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
N    <- 123
x    <- N * df1$n
y    <- rep(3, 37)

keep.going = TRUE
while (keep.going) {
  y <- x * df1$n

  ...

  z <- v * df1$n +  df2$n
  if (some condition) 
    keep.going <- FALSE
}
```

I added a prior assignment of y

The expected result is the operations calculated as is but with y{3], y[5], z[3] and z[5] equals 3 untouched.

y  will be 332592 3070572  3   44403    3    6027       0
and z will be 674203 23714130 3  5789707   3    17680        1

In FORTRAN I have something like this:

```
do i = 1, k1                            
  if (cond(i)) then
    y(i) = x(i) * df1n(i)
  end if
end do

...

do i = 1, k1                        
  if (cond(i)) then
    z(i) = df1n(i) + df2n(i)
  end if
end do
```

Of course implementing this as in FORTRAN is easy and not the way R does thing.

Can anyone point to any documentation or construction I can use to do this?

I am kind of lost.

Thanks again for your time

Comment: `x    <- N * df1` in invalid row. Also, how would your desired output will look like?

Comment: Corrected some things, Added y initialization  and the expected results. Thanks David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subset a vector by logical vector `cond`, positions where `cond==TRUE` is returned. So you can do a partial assignment as,

```
y <- rep(3, 7)
z <- rep(3, 7)
y[cond] <- x[cond] * df1$n[cond]
z[cond] <- v[cond] * df1$n[cond] +  df2$n[cond]
cbind(y, z)
#           y        z
#[1,]  332592   674203
#[2,] 3070572 23714130
#[3,]       3        3
#[4,]   44403  5789707
#[5,]       3        3
#[6,]    6027    17680
#[7,]       0        1
```

Cautionary note: if `y` and `cond` are not of the same length, `cond` is recycled to be of the same lenth as `y`.

```
y <- rep(3, 14)
y[cond] <- x[cond] * df1$n[cond] 
y
#[1]  332592 3070572       3   44403       3    6027       0  332592 3070572       3   44403
#[12]       3    6027       0
```

And, of course, you can loop through the value of `cond` as in Fortran

```
y    <- rep(3,7)
for(i in seq_along(cond)){
    if(cond[i])
    y[i] <- x[i] * df1$n[i]
}
```